# Разбиение строки на несколько по символу или регулярному выражению в SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

В C# была замечательная функция Split, которая возвращала несколько строк, разбив входящую по указанному символу. Есть ли аналог в SQL?

**Например:**

Если раньше у меня были строки:

```
|<имя_столбца>|
|      3      |
|      5      |
|      7      |
```

И проверка:

```
 ...WHERE <имя_таблицы_1>.<имя_столбца> = <имя_таблицы_2>.<имя_столбца>
```

То сейчас строки приобрели вид:

```
|<имя_столбца>|
|     3, 8    |
|     5, 0    |
|     7,6     |
```

И проверка:

```
 ...WHERE <имя_таблицы_1>.<имя_столбца> IN (Split(<имя_таблицы_2>.<имя_столбца>), ',')
```

То есть чтобы функция возвращала список строк из строки, да еще и лишние пробелы подчищая.

Comment: можно попробовать выкрутиться с помощью функции `regexp_instr` или написать свою функцию, которой будите передавать 2 параметра

Comment: Я не понял, это вы так связь "многие ко многим" делаете? Надеюсь, что нет.

Comment: Боюсь, за то как хранить данные я ответить не могу, участвует третья сторона, поэтому прошу подсказать именно из сложившейся ситуации.

Comment: А самое простое что можно сделать, это тупо убрать пробелы и использовать обычный like, как то так: `','||replace(<имя_таблицы_2>.<имя_столбца>,' ','')||',' like '%,'||<имя_таблицы_1>.<имя_столбца>||',%'`

Comment: @Mike в целом, это можно использовать как ответ, да.